# Ignoring XSD Sequence Order on Serialization in .NET

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, xsd

I am consuming a 3rd-party web service (of which, I have no control over) in .NET.

I noticed *some* of my properties were not being set when the response was returning and being serialized from the service.

I have noticed something strange with their response though.

This is a sample of their WSDL

```
<xs:complexType name="letters">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="tns:response">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="a" type="xs:long" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="b" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="c" nillable="true" type="tns:anotherComplexType" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="d" type="xs:dateTime" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="e" type="tns:string" />
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="f" type="tns:boolean" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And this is a sample of the relevant part of the response:

```
<letters>
    <a>0</a>
    <b>2015-02-03T11:59:18+11:00</b>
    <d>2015-02-03T12:00:00+11:00</d>
    <f>true</f>
</letters>
```

I suspect that because they are defining a `<xs:sequence>` for the elements in the `<letters>` part, that the .NET Serializer is expecting the response to have **ALL** elements present in the response? (And thus, their response breaks their WSDL definition?).

Thanks

**EDIT**
It appears that the response is returning an unknown element, specifically

```
<letters>
    <a>0</a>
    <b>2015-02-03T11:59:18+11:00</b>
    <d>2015-02-03T12:00:00+11:00</d>
    <otherElement>blue</otherElement>
    <f>true</f>
</letters>
```

Which is not part of the WSDL. This means that the `<f>` element is not being serialized. Is there a way for me to disregard unknown elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `xsd:sequence` merely means that the elements must be in order.  It is the `@minOccurs` attribute on each `xs:element` that indicates requiredness.  **When `@minOccurs = 0`, the element is optional.**  (Note that the default values for `@minOccurs` and `@maxOccurs` is `1`, indicated "required".)  Since many of the elements in that sequence are `@minOccurs = 0`, all elements do not have to be present in your response.

Comment: Thanks, that is correct in the context of my original question, but it appears they are returning an unknown element as part of their response. Is there anyway to disregard this?

Comment: If they're returning a response that includes elements that are not allowed per the WSDL response XSD, then they are in violation of the interface contract.  Tell them to fix their code or fix their XSD.